# Write single attribute in EtherNet/IP

Tags: python, industrial

My question will be about Cpppo and EtherNET/IP.
I have installed the library Cpppo via pip and trying to set single value in certain class, but i'm doing something wrong, cause every time I am getting "NONE". My test code is:

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple

via = proxy_simple( '192.168.100.7')
with via:
    result, = via.write( [('@0x7F/1/1 = (INT)1')], 1)
```

Also I used Wireshark to get info about service and found, that service value is 0x4D, but in my case I need 0x10. Is it possible to make such kind of request using Cpppo library? 
Screenshot from Wireshark program
[image]
P.S.
I'm sorry if my question was very stupid. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day and a half I found right way how to write single attribute in certain class using Cpppo library. I hope, that my solution will helps to someone. This code works with my hardware in right way:

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple

via = proxy_simple('192.168.100.11')
with via:
    result, = via.read([('@0x7F/1/1=(SINT)1','@0x7F/1/1')],1)
```

And there is screenshot from Wireshark
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPfGd.png)